# Is there a way to automatically add identifiers to images in R Markdown?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Because of some other javascript I'm trying to implement, I would like to be able to easily distinguish and locate images in compiled RMarkdown file. Images generated in a standard way with such chunks of code

````
```{r}
plot1 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, group = am, color = am)) +
    geom_point(size = 3)

plot1
```
````

result in HTML like

```
<img src = "data:image/png..." width = 1000/>
```

I would like to be able to automatically add the unique identifier to each image so that every such call results in something like

```
<img src = "data:image/png..." id = "plot1" width = 1000/>
```

I could probably write this in JS but I wonder if there is a way to do this with some RMarkdown options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a chunk option hook like this:

```
knitr::opts_hooks$set(out.extra = function(options) {
  options$out.extra <- paste0(ifelse(!is.logical(options$out.extra), options$out.extra, "")," id='", options$label, "'")
  options
})
```

Now, if `out.extra` is either `T` or not logical, an id equal to the chunk label will be added. In case it is not logical but rather of type character, its value will be inserted before the id attribute. Consider the following example where we add a border to the plot. The id is set as well!

Full example:

````
---
title: "Out.Extra"
author: "Martin Schmelzer"
date: "10/9/2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

knitr::opts_hooks$set(out.extra = function(options) {
  options$out.extra <- paste0(ifelse(!is.logical(options$out.extra), options$out.extra, "")," id='", options$label, "'")
  options
})
```

## Slide with Plot

```{r pressure, out.extra = 'style="border: red 3px solid;"'}
plot(pressure)
```
````

[image]

Alternatively, take a look at the package [kfigr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kfigr/vignettes/introduction.html#first-chunk).

Comment: Thank you @Yihui !